# How to display some object data inside array object Flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, image, object

i hope you have a great day, i'm still learn Flutter, and i have some difficulties to display some data

so i have this List data

```
listData = [{someData: Lorem #1, image: linkToSomeImage}]
```

and i need to display the image to Image.network(image),

but i don't know why, i tried `listData[0].image or listData[0]["image"]` to populate the variable but it can't works, and got all the red :(

what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have the list of json(`Map`), data will be accessed by operator `[]` with `key`

```
listData[0]["image"]
```

and usage will be

```
Row(
  children: [
    for(int i=0; i< listData.length; i++)
      Image.network(listData[i]['image`]),
  ]
)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, i use this, but i got `RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)`

Comment: Please share a log

Comment: Make sure you have `final listData = [{'someData': 'Lorem #1', 'image': 'linkToSomeImage'}]`

Comment: To be honest the problem is not with the display, the problem is i forgot to run the function to get the data from the API and populate the `listData` :)))